# weird MYSQL hex to decimal

Tags: mysql, type-conversion, hex, decimal

While

> (000000000000000000000000000000000)16 = (0)10
>
> (000000000000000000000000000000001)16 = (1)10
>
> (000000000000000000000000000000002)16 = (2)10

for some reason from this code

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS doiterate;
CREATE PROCEDURE doiterate()
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_max int UNSIGNED DEFAULT 10;
    DECLARE v_counter int UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE orderId BINARY(16) DEFAULT 0x00000000000000000000000000000000;
    DECLARE heldUntil DATETIME DEFAULT '2023-03-31 08:36:35';
    DECLARE orderId_dec BIGINT;

    WHILE v_counter <= v_max DO
            SET v_counter = v_counter + 1;
            INSERT INTO experimental_held_orders
            VALUES (orderId, heldUntil);
            SET orderId_dec = CONV(orderId, 16, 10);
            SET orderId_dec = orderId_dec + 1;
            SET orderId = CONV(orderId_dec, 10, 16);        
            SET heldUntil = heldUntil + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE ;
    
    END WHILE;
END;
CALL doiterate();
```

I get

[image]

Can someone explain me why do I get this result?

UPDATE

Please also tell me how can I get

```
0x00000000000000000000000000000000
0x00000000000000000000000000000001
0x00000000000000000000000000000002
```

etc

Comment: `SET orderId_dec = CONV(orderId, 16, 10);` is incorrect. See parameters description, pay attention to their datatypes.

Comment: `0x31` will null padding is the same as the characterstring `1` because "31" is the hex for the character "1".